# Updating user meta

Tags: users, user-meta

I'm struggling to figure out to get the code to update a single current user meta. For instance if I want to update their first name automatically. I'm using

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

to call the current user data rather than specifying a particular user ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of two functions you'll need; `update_user_meta` or `add_user_meta` - more often than not you'll just need the former, but it's worth noting the difference:

> [`add_post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) will only create an entry if the `$unique` parameter is false, or if there is **no** existing data for `$meta_key`. [`update_post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) will add if no data exists yet, otherwise it will update, depending on if/what you specified for `$prev_value`.

Both functions take the same three initial parameters; a user ID, a meta key, and a value:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user->ID; // The current user ID
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id(); // Alternative for getting current user ID

// Update current user's first name
update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'first_name', 'Jimbo' );

// Update a specific user's first name
update_user_meta( 4 /* User ID 4 */, 'first_name', 'Janey' );
```

Comment: Thanks for this works great - just one more question, if the meta was numerical (eg Age) and I wanted to increase by 1 what would insert in here?

Comment: Get the value with `get_user_meta( $id, 'age' )`, increment by 1 (or set it to 1 if it's currently null), then update.